# How to restrict adb From firing Intents on Android platform?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app which uses intent filter ?

```
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="x" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I can start this app from adb as

```
adb shell am start -a x
```

This can enable a Hacker to start an activity and launch an attack if this activity is BluetoothDevice Picker activity or `WifiPickerActivity` ?

How this can be restricted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android has some security features in place for the situation you mentioned. The first one is that adb is not enabled by default. If adb is enabled from Android 4.2.2 there's a system dialog that appears when you connect adb to make sure you have the right to unlock and accept the RSA signature of the computer that is trying to connect to the device (usually this dialog also has a checkbox to permanently accept that RSA signature, you can leave that unchecked for extra security)

In "Settings -> Developer options" of the android device you also have the option to disable usb debugging.

Otherwise the features of the activity manager (am) are necessary for developers, even though you could get "hacked" (only if this hacker already has access to the computer connected to the Android device).

For more info on adb: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html